# Publishing .NET Core 3.1 web app to Azure App Service Linux using VS 2019 showing Welcome screen

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy my .NET Core 3.1 MVC web application on Azure App Service Linux using Visual Studio 2019. All that I can see after deployment is the welcome screen shown below.

[image: Azure welcome screen]

I checked some SO links which asked me to check whether the files are present on **http://{app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net** which I confirmed are there. Check the image below.

[image]

I have also added the correct **Startup Command** on my app service configuration page.

[image]

**EDIT**
Digging a little further, I found the following error log file from Azure.

```
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263485764Z   _____                               
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263521665Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263527465Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263531865Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263535966Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263540366Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263544466Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263548466Z 
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263552066Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263555866Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263559566Z ASP .NETCore Version: 3.1.0
2020-03-11T20:19:14.263563267Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-03-11T20:19:14.438520438Z Running oryx -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -userStartupCommand '' 
2020-03-11T20:19:14.654004939Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20191105.2, Commit: 67e159d71419415435cb5d10c05a0f0758ee8809, ReleaseTagName: 20191105.2
2020-03-11T20:19:14.661143991Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2020-03-11T20:19:14.661606007Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2020-03-11T20:19:14.662016422Z Build Operation ID: e539cda2-065a-4380-8443-113a8833110a
2020-03-11T20:19:16.245422274Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-03-11T20:19:16.918107003Z Trying to find the startup DLL name...
2020-03-11T20:19:16.918873230Z Found the startup D name: BHD.Web.dll
2020-03-11T20:19:16.918885630Z Running the command: dotnet "BHD.Web.dll"
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158001162Z Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158026363Z 
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158031663Z File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158036463Z    at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158041063Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158045763Z    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158052864Z    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158063864Z    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158068564Z    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158072864Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158076964Z    at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158081065Z    at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158085265Z    at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T](Assembly element)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158089465Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(Assembly assembly)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158094665Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String entryAssemblyName)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158098965Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158103165Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158107265Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158111866Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViewsCore(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158115966Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViews(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158120066Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158124266Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddRelatedParts(IdentityBuilder builder)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158128466Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddDefaultUI(IdentityBuilder builder)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158132666Z    at BHD.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Priyank\Projects\ServiceBerry\Sourcecode\BHD.Web\Startup.cs:line 36
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158137267Z    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158141367Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158145567Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158152667Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158157267Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158161567Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158166368Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158170568Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158175068Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158179168Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158183268Z    at BHD.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Priyank\Projects\ServiceBerry\Sourcecode\BHD.Web\Program.cs:line 16
2020-03-11T20:19:21.158187668Z 
2020-03-11T20:19:21.177212339Z 
2020-03-11T20:19:21.207111394Z ptrace(ATTACH, 29) FAILED Operation not permitted
2020-03-11T20:19:21.207772817Z Writing minidump with heap to file /home/logs/dumps/coredump.519bbab76c1d.29.1583957954
2020-03-11T20:19:21.618304499Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: line 12:    29 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet "BHD.Web.dll"
```

Comment: Note the exception is looking for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, Version=3.1.1.0 while your settings are using 3.1.0, this coud be an issue..

Comment: 3.1.1 option is not available for minor version, I may have to downgrade then!

Comment: downgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` to version 3.1.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you don't have the starting page above the `hostingstart.html`. Make sure your default page is listed in here and is above `hostingstart.html` so that it will be picked by default.

You need to set the startup command as dotnet yourapp.dll under general settings.

Also make sure to check "Remove additional files at destination button during republish" on Visual Studio. That will remove the existing files in the WebApp before uploading the files.

Comment: I am afraid, this doesn't help me. I tried "Remove additional files" option. Since I am using the MVC app, I don't think the default page will help.

Comment: I have added some error logs from Azure. Please check if that can help me to solve the issue